# What might be the case with a socketTimeout exception with no message?

Tags: java, tcp

When I write TCP communication through the Java language, a socketTimeout exception occurs, but the exception printed has no message:java.net.SocketTimeoutException
I use this: log.error(e);
The other phenomenon is that both the connection time and the read time are broken and become very long

I try to close the back-end connection and read the back-end timeout, which prints the following exception:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out / java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect... they will has some message

```
    Socket socket = null;
    String ip = null;
    int port = 0;
    OutputStream out = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    String response = null;
    int connTimeout = 3000;
    int readTimeout = 5000;
    try {
        socket = new Socket();
        ip = locationConfig.getHost();
        port = locationConfig.getPort();
        socket.setSendBufferSize(64 * 1024);
        socket.setReceiveBufferSize(64 * 1024);
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        socket.setSoTimeout(readTimeout);
        socket.setKeepAlive(true);
        socket.setSoLinger(true, 0);
        socket.setReuseAddress(false);
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), connTimeout);
        out = socket.getOutputStream();
        out.write("DETECT1".getBytes());
        out.flush();
        socket.shutdownOutput();
        in = socket.getInputStream();
        int length = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[Constants.READ_BUFFER_MAX_SIZE];
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            baos.flush();
        }
        response = new String(baos.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e)
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

I wonder what could have caused it

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved. The problem is server side memory overflow.It may feel like the Java virtual machine can't hand over network data to the upper code when memory is full, causing the timeout set by the upper code to fail. And other oddities.

Comment: Java can't do anything when memory is full, including allocating byte arrays to read from the network into.